# Multi-machine Network Setup: Cannot ping machine on different subnet but the reverse ping works

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, routing, ping

[Ubuntu 18.04]

My connection setup is as follows:

Laptop (Wifi: 192.168.43.181) <---> Jetson 1 [ROS MASTER] (Wifi: 192.168.43.2) | (Ethernet: 10.42.0.1) <--> Jetson 2 (Ethernet: 10.42.0.2)

There is no direct connection between Laptop and jetson2 (they are on different subnets).

I can ping Laptop(192.168.43.181) from my Jetson 2. But I cannot ping Jetson2(10.42.0.2) from my Laptop and hence. Pinging between Laptop-J1 and J1-J2 works both ways.

ipv4_forwarding has been set to 1 on J1. I have also set up the "/etc/hosts" file on all machines with the hostname and IPs.

laptop:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   laptop
192.168.43.2    jetson1
10.42.0.2        jetson2
```

jetson1:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   jetson1
192.168.43.181  laptop
10.42.0.2   jetson2
```

jetson2:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   jetson2
10.42.0.1   jetson1
192.168.43.181  laptop
```

I have even added routes as described in other discussions

laptop:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.223  0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
10.42.0.0       192.168.43.2    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wlp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp1s0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
```

jetson1:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.223  0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlan0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

jetson2:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 eth0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    10.42.0.1       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

When I try to ping 10.42.0.2(Jetson2) from my laptop:

```
PING 10.42.0.2 (10.42.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.43.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.43.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.43.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable ...
```

When I ping 192.168.43.181(laptop) from Jetson2

```
PING 192.168.43.181 (192.168.43.181) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.43.181: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=72.4 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.43.181: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=226 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.43.181: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=60.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.43.181: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=65.8 ms ...
```

Thanks for the help :)